# Link Strange Unicode

Tags: html, unicode

I've a link that when I copy paste it changes.the copied url is

```
https://www.webteb.com/tests/search?Text=الدم
```

the pasted

```
https://www.webteb.com/tests/search?Text=%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D9%85
```

as you can see the word `الدم` is converted to `%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%D9%85`

How does that happen? what is the unicoding type?? how I can understand it?
I try in many ways but I'm still a beginner so I didn't find any good approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've got there is Unicode text first encoded as UTF-8, then each byte of that encoded using URL encoding.

URL encoding replaces each byte by a percent sign (`%`) and two hex digits.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding for more information.

---

Quick example:

- `%20` encodes a single byte, which is UTF-8 for U+0020 (SPACE, ).
- `%D8%A7` encodes two bytes (D8 A7), which is UTF-8 for U+0627 (ARABIC LETTER ALEF, `ا`).
- `%D9%84` encodes two bytes (D9 84), which is UTF-8 for U+0644 (ARABIC LETTER LAM, `ل`).
- etc.

Comment: thank you :) you are a life saver ^_^ in wiki link I found a java class and I use it